# Is mask working differently using inplace?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, mask

I've just found out about this strange behaviour of mask, could someone explain this to me?

A)
[input]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df['C'] ='hi'
df.mask(df[['A', 'B']]<3, inplace=True)
```

[output]

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | NaN | hi |
| 1 | NaN | 3.0 | hi |
| 2 | 4.0 | 5.0 | hi |
| 3 | 6.0 | 7.0 | hi |
| 4 | 8.0 | 9.0 | hi |

B)
[input]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df['C'] ='hi'
df.mask(df[['A', 'B']]<3)
```

[output]

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | 3.0 | NaN |
| 2 | 4.0 | 5.0 | NaN |
| 3 | 6.0 | 7.0 | NaN |
| 4 | 8.0 | 9.0 | NaN |

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO JeB.  Good observation!

Comment: maybe you should do `df = ...`  if you don't use `in-place`. OR maybe you should first read documentation for `df.mask()` - maybe it explains it

Comment: all functions which have option `inplace` work different with or without `inplace=True`. They create `inplace` for some reason - to work in different way.

Comment: The main point is there are different treatments to Column C with and without inplace=True.  One treats values in Column C also meet the criteria and should get changed to NaN (since the parameter `other` of the mask function is default to NaN).  This is nothing to do whether we have re-assigned to the original df

Comment: @furas yes but if I do df=... when in-place is False the output is different respect what I have with in-place=True and that is suspicious

Answer (score 5):

The root cause of different result is that you pass a boolean dataframe that is not the same shape as the dataframe you want to mask. `df.mask()` fill the missing part with the value of `inplace`.

From the sourcecode, you can see [pandas.DataFrame.mask()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L9290-L9325) calls [pandas.DataFrame.where()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L9147-L9288) internally. `pandas.DataFrame.where()` then calls a [_where()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L9002) method that replaces values where the condition is False.

I just take `df.where()` as an example, here is the example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(-1, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df1 = df.where(df[['A', 'B']]<3)

df.where(df[['A', 'B']]<3, inplace=True)
```

In this example, the `df` is

```
   A   B   C
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11
```

`df[['A', 'B']]<3`, the value of `cond` argument, is

```
       A      B
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
```

Digging into `_where()` method, the [following lines](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L9018-L9031) are the key part:

```py
    def _where(...):
        # align the cond to same shape as myself
        cond = com.apply_if_callable(cond, self)
        if isinstance(cond, NDFrame):
            cond, _ = cond.align(self, join="right", broadcast_axis=1)
        ...
        # make sure we are boolean
        fill_value = bool(inplace)
        cond = cond.fillna(fill_value)
```

Since the shape of `cond` and `df` are different, `cond.align()` fills the missing with `NaN` value. After that, `cond` looks like

```
       A      B   C
0   True   True NaN
1  False  False NaN
2  False  False NaN
3  False  False NaN
```

Then with `cond.fillna(fill_value)`, the `NaN` values are replaced with the value of `inplace`. So C column has the same value with `inplace` value.

Though there are still some codes ([L9048](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L9048) and [L9124-L9145](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L9124-L9145)) related with `inplace`. We needn't care about the detail, since the aim of these lines are to replace values where the condition is False.

Recall that the `df` is

```
   A   B   C
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11
```

- `df1=df.where(df[['A', 'B']]<3)`: The `cond` C column is False since the default value of `inplace` is False. After doing `df.where()`, the `df` C column is set to the value of `other` argument which is `NaN` by default.
- `df.where(df[['A', 'B']]<3, inplace=True)`: The `cond` C column is True. After doing `df.where()`, the `df` C column keeps the same.

```
# print(df1)
     A    B   C
0  0.0  1.0 NaN
1  NaN  NaN NaN
2  NaN  NaN NaN
3  NaN  NaN NaN

# print(df) after df.where(df[['A', 'B']]<3, inplace=True)
     A    B   C
0  0.0  1.0   2
1  NaN  NaN   5
2  NaN  NaN   8
3  NaN  NaN  11
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it simple.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df['C'] ='hi'
df.mask(df[['A', 'B']]<3)
```

The last code line is asking for the full dataframe (`df.`). The condition was applied to columns `['A', 'B']` so, once the column 'C' was not part of the condition it will return `NaN` for the column `C`.

This below would be the same of `df.mask(df[['A', 'B']]<3)`

```
>>> df[["A","B","C"]].mask(df[['A', 'B']]<3)
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  3.0  NaN
2  4.0  5.0  NaN
3  6.0  7.0  NaN
4  8.0  9.0  NaN
>>>
```

And, `df.mask(df[['A', 'B', 'C']]<3)` will generate an error, because column 'C' is string type

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Finally, to return only columns `"A" and "B"`

```
>>> df[["A","B"]].mask(df[['A', 'B']]<3)
     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  3.0
2  4.0  5.0
3  6.0  7.0
4  8.0  9.0
```

When you apply the command to be done `inplace`, it will do nothing to column `C` because of the NaN, which in the `mask` method will be 'do nothing'